# Terraform, Windows, Userdata with a batch script

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, user-data

I have a batch script called Windows_network_adp.bat. The contents are:

```
 <script>
 netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static 10.*.*.* 255.*.*.*
 </script>
```

It basically adds a static IP to the 2nd NIC on a Windows EC2. This batch file works if i manually paste the contents into the AWS Console user data section. I want it to come in automatically with terraform.

I have tried the following so far:

#### 1st Try

```
user_data_base64  = base64encode(<<EOF
<script>
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static 10.*.*.* 255.*.*.*
</script>
EOF
)
```

#### 2nd Try

```
user_data_base64            = base64encode(file("build/Windows_network_adp.bat"))
```

No errors on terraform apply. but when i remote into the windows ec2 the network adaptor is still set to dhcp and my static entry has not been applied.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So Just to Update problem solved.

The syntax of how to do user data in this instance is below. unfortunately the problem was the 2nd interface is being created in terraform after the Windows EC2 therefore my userdata configuring a static IP on the 2nd NIC is irrelevant as it isn't created yet. No base 64 encoding is needed for user data as i have a powershell script now doing another function. There isn't much information on userdata for a batch script out there so i hope this helps other people and prevent them going down a rabbit hole like we did.

```
user_data                   = <<EOF
<script>
netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet 3" static "10.*.*.*" "*.*.*.*"
</script>
EOF
```